# How to increase extents on a date axis in d3?

Tags: javascript, datetime, d3.js

I have a line chart in d3.  The x-axis is dates.  I want to increase the extents a bit so that the first and last data points do not land right at the first and last date on the chart.  Here is a pic of the chart:
[image]

Notice how the first data point and last data point are right at the beginning and end of the chart?  I'd like a little margin on both sides, that is the smallest date should be a little smaller and the biggest date should be a little bigger.  Is there an easy way to extend the extents?

Here is the way it is currently created:

```
x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.date; }));
```

**EDIT:** The date is dynamic and could be a few days or a few decades. I'm hoping for an answer that looks at the date range and adds something like 5% more to each end.  Also please provide a solution that does not depend on adding another library, which can conflict with existing library functions.

For example, the solution below by Gerardo depends on adding an additional library in order to get the count function to work.  But that interferes with the axis function later in the code.

The only way to get the following code to work:

```
  const minDate = new Date("October 10, 2010");
  const maxDate = new Date("January 31, 2020");
  const daysBetween = d3.timeDay.count(minDate,maxDate);
```

is to include this library:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```

But that causes the following code that is used later to fail:

```
  var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x)
    .ticks(d3.time.years,1)
    .tickSize(10)
    .orient("bottom");
```

This is my attempt at a solution.  I get the min and max date from the extents, convert those to milliseconds, then subtract 5% from the min, add 5% to the max, then set the new extents:

```
  var xSpan = maxTime - minTime;
  console.log("maxTime=" +maxTime +", minTime=" +minTime +", xSpan="+xSpan);
  xMarg = xSpan * 0.05;  
  xMarg = xMarg.toFixed(0); //nearest millisecond
  console.log("xMarg="+xMarg);
  var minDate = new Date(minTime-xMarg);
  var maxDate = new Date(maxTime+xMarg);
  console.log("minDate="+minDate +", maxDate="+maxDate);
  x.domain([minDate,maxDate]);
```

But the maxDate output shows an error:

> maxTime=1580454000000, minTime=1288332000000, xSpan=292122000000
>   xMarg=14606100000     minDate=Wed May 12 2010 22:45:00 GMT-0600
>   (Mountain Daylight Time), maxDate=Invalid Date

Comment: All the answers so far assume a know date range.  The date range could be a few days or a few decades.  I'm hoping for an answer that looks at the date range and adds something like 5% more to each end.

Comment: Well, in that case you should have made it clear in the question (the way it is we have no clue that the data is dynamic or that you don't know it in advance). I've edited my answer.

Comment: My solution does not ask to add any additional library. That is D3, version 5. If you have a previous version of D3 you should have made that clear in the question (again, it was impossible to know that just by reading the question itself). Anyway, you keep editing your question to add more and more information that you didn't make clear at first, so I'm not wasting more time in this question. I hope someone else helps you.

Answer (score 2):

The [d3-time](https://github.com/d3/d3-time) module has some handy methods you can use, in your case [`interval.offset`](https://github.com/d3/d3-time#interval_offset). You can choose if you want to add/subtract milliseconds, seconds, minutes, hours, days, weeks, months or years.

For instance, if you want to add 15 days to a date, like today:

```js
const todayPlus15days = d3.timeDay.offset(new Date(), 15);
//Interval type and offset-----^-----------------------^

console.log("In 15 days, it will be: " + todayPlus15days);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```

In your case, let's subtract/add 2 months. For that, we'll change `d3.extent` for `d3.min`/`d3.max`:

```
x.domain([d3.timeMonth.offset(d3.min(data, function(d) {
    return d.date;
  }), -2),//subtracting 2 months
  d3.timeMonth.offset(d3.max(data, function(d) {
    return d.date;
  }), 2)//adding 2 months
])
```

It's worth mentioning that `d3.timeMonth.offset(date, 2)` might seem the same of `d3.timeDay.offset(date, 60)`, but 60 days are not necessarily 2 months. In your case such precision is not important, though.

---

**EDIT**

According to [your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60482044/how-to-increase-extents-on-a-date-axis-in-d3/60482206#comment106997831_60482044),

> All the answers so far assume a know date range. The date range could be a few days or a few decades. I'm hoping for an answer that looks at the date range and adds something like 5% more to each end.

That is also easy to implement. First, we set the percentage (5%, for instance) and then we get the date interval. For bigger precision you can use seconds or even milliseconds, but I'll use days here (`d3.timeDay.count`). Finally, you set the offsets (start/end) according to the percentage.

Here is a demo:

```js
const date1 = new Date("March 19, 2019");
const date2 = new Date("December 10, 2019");
const percentage = 0.05;
const numberOfDays = d3.timeDay.count(date1, date2);
const domain = [d3.timeDay.offset(date1, -(~~(numberOfDays * percentage))),
  d3.timeDay.offset(date2, +(~~(numberOfDays * percentage)))
];

console.log(domain)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you Gerado!  I never knew about the ~~ operator either.  I'm assuming that rounds to the nearest integer.  I will probably use milliseconds instead, just to make sure all possibilities are covered.

Answer (score 0):

You can find out min max in advanced and add/subtract year/month from that and use it as domain instead:

```
....
let extent = d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.date; });
x.domain([addYear(extent[0], -1), addYear(extent[1], 1));
...
...
function addYear(date, number) {
    var year = date.getFullYear();
    var month = date.getMonth();
    var day = date.getDate();
    var c = new Date(year + number, month, day);
}
...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add a value to date at both ends and add it to X domain. You will automatically get margins at both ends.Hope this helps.

```
//assuming that date is in years
let min=Number.MAX_VALUE;
let max=Number.MIN_VALUE;
for (var property in data) {
  let date = data[property].date;
  if( date<min ){
     min = date;   
  }
  if( date>max ){
    max = date;
  }
}
//once we find min and max, assign it to domian of x-axis
x.domain(min-1,max+1);
```